# Blender says model is UV Unwrapped but cycles does not render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, uv

I can't get my model to render with the UV Unwraps. Though, there are many clues saying the model is in fact unwrapped, Blender can't render them out.

Here is the model in textured view:

[image: textured view]

Here it is in rendered mode (I linked the texture to the glossy color for visualization sake):

[image: rendered view]

Here is the node setup:

[image: Node setup]

And here is the unwrap:

[image: Unwrap]

Any suggestions on what could be the problem? Appreciate it.

Comment: Not sure, but somehow your texture coordinates in the 3D view don't seem to be matching the UV layout in the image editor. Could you edit your question post a link to your blendfile?

Comment: Well, it is part of a 60MB file and all its textures are already appended. Going to try to make it apart but not sure if I am going to get it. EDIT: It's been uploaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8c37r29zlv9stau/UVs.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is having two UV maps in the same object, and the one you want is not the active one.

Normally this is not a problem but you have to choose which one to use for rendering, or change from a *Texture Corrdinate* node to a *UV* node.

[image: UV maps]

[image: UV Node]

Comment: Thank you for the support, mate. I apologize for creating this question, after nearly two hours of research it was just something stupid like that which I completely forgot. Once again, I appreciate it!